# Where is selectMany in ReactiveCocoa 0.10.0

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reactive-programming

The ReactiveCocoa API has gone under some major changes recently and I cannot find the substitute function for the selectMany operator in version 0.10.0.

```
// RACSubscribableProtocol.h in version 0.8.2
// Gets a new subscribable for every `next` and sends `next` when any of those
// subscribables do.
- (RACSubscribable *)selectMany:(id<RACSubscribable> (^)(id x))selectBlock;
```

I see that RACSubscribable became RACSignal but it doesn't have the selectMany operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `-[RACStream flattenMap:]`

Thanks for the response at https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/176